# Ternary Operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, conditional-operator

Why compiler cannot specialize this function and is there a way to force him to do so?
**The error I'm getting:

Error   1   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type' Ternary::check(bool,Left,Right)'**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

template<int v>
struct Int2Type
{
    enum {value = v};
};

template<bool condition,class Left, class Right>
struct Result;


template<class Left, class Right>
struct Result<true,Left,Right>
{
    typedef Left value;
};

template<class Left, class Right>
struct Result<false,Left,Right>
{
    typedef Right value;
};

struct Ternary
{
    template<class Left, class Right>
    static Right check_(Int2Type<false>, Left left, Right right)
    {
        return right;
    }

    template<class Left, class Right>
    static Left check_(Int2Type<true>, Left left, Right right)
    {
        return left;
    }


__Updated__
    template<bool Condition,class Left, class Right>
static auto check(Left left, Right right)->
    typename Result<Condition,Left,Right>::value
{
    return check_(Int2Type<Condition>,left,right);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    string s = "Hello";
    cout << Ternary::check<false>(a,s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav C++03 it can be thought as a "subset" of C++0x so your edit is inapropriate for C++0x covers it.

Comment: Yes, but SO isn't that bright.  If you search for questions tagged "c++", SO won't list this question.

Comment: There's no error on the `decltype` with g++ 4.5. It only complains about the `check_(Int2Type<condition>,left,right);` line.

Comment: @KennyTM by complians you mean warns or gives an error?

Comment: @There: Errors of course. A template parameter must be a constant expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough experience with C++0x yet, but from what I see:

```
    decltype(Result<(sizeof(int) == 1),Left,Right>::value)
```

`decltype` expects an expression, but `Result<...>::value` is a type. Just remove the `decltype`;

```
    return check_(Int2Type<condition>,left,right);
```

`condition` is a variable, you can't use it as a template parameter.

UPDATE: also `Int2Type<Condition>` is again a type. You want to pass a value: `Int2Type<Condition>()`.

Comment: @ybungalobill Similarly to the sizeof operator, the operand of decltype is unevaluated.[9] Informally, the type returned by decltype(e) is deduced as follows:[1]

If the expression e refers to a __variable__ in local or namespace scope, a static member variable or a function parameter, then the result is that variable's or parameter's declared type 
If e is a function call or an overloaded operator invocation, decltype(e) denotes the declared return type of that function 
Otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e; if e is an rvalue, the result is T

Comment: @There: It has nothing to do with evaluation. **Grammar** says that the thing between the parenthesizes must be an **expression**, what you wrote there is a **type**.

Comment: @ybungalobill ok got it. But I can remove decltype - it wont compile

Comment: @There: if it doesn't compile without decltype you may try to add `typename` before result (and remove decltype).

Comment: @ybunalobill adding typename helped. Thanks. Now (I've updated my post) complianes about check_(...);